# Use a variable defined from a custom form in a custom template

Tags: theming, forms, 8

I created a custom form, a custom template, and I "linked" both with a theme hook.

In the `buildForm()` method, I used the following code.

```php
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['#foo'] = array("key_a"=>"value_a", "key_b"=>"value_b", "key_c"=>"value_c");
  // …
  return $form;
}
```

From the template, when I show all the available variables with `{{ dump() }}` or `{{ kint() }}` I see `#foo` is present, but I cannot print its value.

I tried the following code, but either I get an error or `NULL` is printed.

```
{{ element.#foo }}
{{ element.'#foo' }}
{{ 'element.#foo' }}
{{ foo }}
```

How can I print that value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like javascript you need to use bracket notation to get hash key variables:

```
{{ element['#foo'].key_a }}
```